# SQL using case or if in function

Tags: sql-server

I have table of persons with first and middle names. I'm trying to write a function that check if in given names contains certain letters. For example 'oistmiahf' will return 'Smith'.

I am trying to make it with case:

```
CREATE FUNCTION dbo.ufn_FindNames(@lettersToSearch nvarchar(50))
    RETURNS nvarchar(max)
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @firstName nvarchar(50) = (SELECT FirstName FROM Employees),
    @middleName nvarchar(50) = (SELECT MiddleName FROM Employees),
    @ifNoResult nvarchar(50) = 'No result'

    RETURN CASE
        WHEN (@firstName LIKE '%' + @lettersToSearch + '%') THEN @firstName + ' '
        WHEN (@middleName LIKE '%' + @lettersToSearch + '%') THEN @middleName + ' '
        ELSE @ifNoResult
    END
END
GO
```

After this when I call function with " *EXEC dbo.ufn_FindNames'oistmiahf'* " I get error 
**" Subquery returned more than 1 value. This is not permitted when the subquery follows =, !=, <, <= , >, >= or when the subquery is used as an expression. "**

If I try to make the same function, but with IF contition I have again same error.

```
CREATE FUNCTION dbo.ufn_FindNames(@lettersToSearch nvarchar(50))
    RETURNS nvarchar(50)
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @firstName nvarchar(50) = (SELECT FirstName FROM Employees), 
    @middleName nvarchar(50) = (SELECT MiddleName FROM Employees),
    @result nvarchar(50)

    IF(@firstName LIKE '%' + @lettersToSearch + '%')
    BEGIN
        RETURN @firstName + ' '
    END


    IF(@middleName LIKE '%' + @lettersToSearch + '%')
    BEGIN
        RETURN @middleName + ' '
    END

    RETURN @result
END
GO
```

Comment: Even if you fix that error, your function doesn't come close to doing what you want.

Comment: Error is in `DECLARE @firstName nvarchar(50) = (SELECT FirstName FROM Employees),
    @middleName nvarchar(50) = (SELECT MiddleName FROM Employees)`. Here `Employees` table has **more than one row** that's why you got this error and Gordon is right.

Comment: Ax yes I add to "SELECT FirstName FROM Employees", "WHERE FirstName = @firstName" and now it works without error but how should I change it to work correct

Comment: Instead of LIKE have a look at PATINDEX http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188395.aspx